# Master-details using ReactiveUI via WhenAnyValue doesn't work for me

Tags: wpf, mvvm, system.reactive, master-detail, reactiveui

I am implementing a typical master-details GUI pattern using WPF and ReactiveUI. I would like to keep the master viewmodel and the details viewmodel decoupled from each other without resorting to something more fragile and indirect like message bus. However something isn't working.

I have two questions:

1. Why is `WhenAnyValue` not working in my code below?
2. What is the
   recommended way of implementing decoupled master-details in
   ReactiveUI nowadays?

Code:

```cs
public class ShellViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ShellViewModel(OrderListViewModel orderListViewModel, OrderDetailsViewModel orderDetailsViewModel)
    {
        OrderListViewModel = orderListViewModel;
        OrderDetailsViewModel = orderDetailsViewModel;

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.OrderListViewModel.SelectedOrderHeader).Do(h =>
        {
            OrderDetailsViewModel.Set(h);
        });
    }

    public OrderListViewModel OrderListViewModel { get; }
    public OrderDetailsViewModel OrderDetailsViewModel { get; }
}
```

I have omitted the two underlying viewmodels and related views because they are very typical (observable list + selected item property) and seem to be working fine by themselves.

**Update:** the the #1 can be "fixed" by using `Subscribe` instead of `Do`. I don't know what is the purpose of the latter?

Comment: Do you have your RaiseAndSet.. in OrderListViewModel.SelectedOrderHeader?

Comment: @tagaPdyk thanks, but that is not the problem, I have updated the question with my latest discovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is WhenAnyValue not working in my code below?

Because Rx observables (like the one returned from your `WhenAnyValue`) are lazy by nature. That means, nothing is going to happen until you call `Subscribe` on them. As you stated...

> the the #1 can be "fixed" by using Subscribe instead of Do. I don't know what is the purpose of the latter?

Its' purpose is to introduce side effects to your Rx stream. For example, you could inject some logging into this method.

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.OrderListViewModel.SelectedOrderHeader)
    .Do(_ => Console.WriteLine("Order selected!")
    .Subscribe(h => OrderDetailsViewModel = h);
```

Note that [introducing side effects in Rx should generally be avoided](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/09_SideEffects.html#Do).

> What is the recommended way of implementing decoupled master-details in ReactiveUI nowadays?

Your code looks fine to me. Alternative approach which comes to my mind is exposing `IObservable<OrderDetailsViewModel>` directly from the `OrderListViewModel`.

Oh, and apart from that, you should definitely consider feeding these view models to [ObservableAsPropertyHelper](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/framework/prefer-oaph-over-properties) in your `ShellViewModel` class.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer!